# Eclipse compiling problem

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, compiler-errors

Is there a way to set Eclipse report compile errors same as javac?

I stumble upon few cases where something is working in eclipse, and cannot be compiled with javac. I understand that eclipse uses ECJ and that cannot be changed, but can it anywhere be set that everything that cannot compile with javac be a compile error in Eclipse? (since there are few things that you can make compile errors in Eclipse even if they are ok)

Examples are from `@SuiteClasses({A.class,B.class,})` (last comma is the problem),  to subtle generic problems that I fully don't understand.

Comment: I had known Eclipse used ECJ, but I hadn't realized there was a difference between what it could and could not compile compared to Sun's implementation. I thought there was some standard or specification that had to be followed.

Comment: Yes, I've experienced similar problems as OP. The rule of thumb is that Eclipse is more tolerant than javac/ant. So committing a compiling code to CVS may cause the continuous-integration server to fail with the build on compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse uses ECJ for compilation via the [Java Builder](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-java-builder.htm) that is responsible for compiling and indexing all Java source files in order to make incremental compilation easier (making it easier for errors to be reported), apart from aiding refactoring and search operations.

ECJ happens to be the default and only compiler used by the Java builder; the compiler used cannot be configured. One cannot change it. However, you could attempt to add your own builder that uses an Ant build script relying on the javac compiler of the Sun JDK.

Comment: Could you explain how to change eclipse to use ant build script, or give some links related to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can make eclipse build use ant, that will in turn use javac.

Answer (score 0):

Both, Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ) and Javac, are based on the Java Language Specification (JLS) and hence are supposed to report the same errors.

However there are cases where where the behavior differs. At times the reason is bugs as is the case in any large piece of software, and at times the JLS is a bit ambiguous causing it to be interpreted slightly differently by both compilers. At times ECJ is at fault and at times Javac is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can [change your Eclipse preferences](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/04/12/eclipse-improve-code/) to more restrictive `javac`-esque equivalents. This will produce warnings or errors for what you define when compiling--you can even define errors/warnings for everything!!